# make array value key for another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have value in table like this :

```
id entity_id   value
1    1        summer test
2    1        summer-test
3    2        winter test
4    2        winter-test
```

Iam using this sql query to fetch result from dbase:

```
$query = 'SELECT entity_id,value FROM blogs';
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

It gives me result in this form:

```
   [0] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 1   // this is common, so this should be key for new array
                    [value] => summer event
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 1
                    [value] => summer-event
                )

............... and so on....
```

Now I want the new array to be like this:

```
 [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => summer event
            [path] => summer-event
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => test event
            [path] => test-event
        )
```

I tried this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($results as $v)
{
   $newArray[$v['entity_id']] = $v['value'];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

It gives the last value for all entity_id

```
Array
(
    [1] => summer-test
    [2] => winter-test
)
```

Comment: Why doesn't the database have the columns `name` and `path`?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried in order to get the desired array? (Please also include any errors you ran into.)

Comment: @Aashi have you ever heard about column alias ?

Comment: I tried: foreach($results as $result){

$blogs[] = array(
$result['entity_id']=> $result['value']

); I googled but I didnt get any desired result.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. That I had tried to get the desired result. but it just gives the last value as expected. How can i get all the values for same key?

Comment: @Aashi check that query which i updated and try.

Answer (score 1):

As your values are depending on your existing columns you can work try this query to get your output and then you can process your array.

```
$query = 'SELECT value AS name,REPLACE(value ,' ','-') AS path FROM blogs';
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

In 2nd column it will replace the space with your (-).
It will return you

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => summer event
            [path] => summer-event
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test event
            [path] => test-event
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have the name stored in the database the only option here would be to process the resulting array before you use it.

```
// Create a new empty array
$proccessed_array = array();

// loop through the existing array and populate the new array
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $proccessed_array[] = array(
        'name' => str_replace('-', ' ', $result['value']), // You modify the path in order to be used as name
        'path' => $result['value'] // You keep this value to the new array
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a dataset based on your example for `$results`:

```
$results = [
    [
        'entity_id' => 3,
        'value' => 'Fall Event',
    ],
    [
        'entity_id' => 2,
        'value' => 'Summer Event',
    ],
    [
        'entity_id' => 1,
        'value' => 'Spring Event',
    ],
    [
        'entity_id' => 4,
        'value' => 'Winter Event',
    ],

];

$events = array_reduce($results, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['entity_id']] = [
        'name' => $item['value'],
        'path' => $item['value'],
    ];

    return $carry;
}, $inital = []);

print_r($events);
```

This displays the following:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fall Event
            [path] => Fall Event
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Summer Event
            [path] => Summer Event
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Spring Event
            [path] => Spring Event
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Winter Event
            [path] => Winter Event
        )

)
```